# An expression for quick and nervous behaviour

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, vocabulary

I am looking for the verb or expression to use to describe when for instance you type quickly and nervously on your computer keyboard, perhaps to find something (on a search engine for instance).

Comment: Do you mean when you mishit the keys or make a typo?

Comment: No, just the action of typing quickly and nervously..something we all do everyday I think. Is there a specific verb or expression for this?

Comment: I might call that 'hammering away at the keyboard', though that could imply merely hitting the keys rather hard -- not necessarily typing quickly.

Comment: I really don't think typing _nervously_ is something we all do on a daily basis. I'm quite sure I only do it very rarely, in fact.

Comment: Stop fidgeting on the keyboard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it has to describe

- typing on a keyboard
- nervously and quickly
- that you are trying to find something

These are such unrelated concepts (especially the third one in connection to the other two!) that the chances of a language having come up with an expression to coincidentally exactly describe those three concepts applying all together are very slim at best.

The only time that happens is if and when the need for such an expression arises because people encounter the need to express the combined concepts quite often. Which I doubt is the case for this example.

However, apart from set phrases, you could introduce the concepts contextually:

> He was frantically googling.

- Would indicate his use of a well-know search engine.
- Which in turn tells us is is trying to find something.
- Since we know that using google means we type things, we know he is typing.
- The use of *frantically* tells us he is doing it in what may be described as fast and nervously.

(I assume you meant a search engine, not a **research** engine...)

Comment: +1. Exactly what my thoughts were, including the fact that _frantically_ is the most natural word to describe the ‘nervous’ part of things.

Comment: You can use google without typing. Google Now on Android allows you to google by voice. So frantically googling could be yammering into your android phone.

Comment: @davoid: I am making the assumption here that someone who exhibits the described behaviour would do so in a similar way substituting a way of talking for a way of typing if they were to use a voice-operated system. The question was to describe the behaviour in the question, not to find a sentence that can not describe anything else :P

Comment: @oerkelens Gotcha. Carry on ;-)

Comment: Though *franticly* is also listed on dictionaries, *frantically* is far more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=franticly%2C+frantically

Comment: @Kris: good point, I edited it :)

Comment: *Frantically googling* describes 90% of my life.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I have ever heard anyone use "Fumbling at..." in this kind of context.

Consider

> ...frenetically searching for something on the computer

"Frenetically" implies speed and possibly not 100% accuracy, whereas "frantically" just implies speed and possibly frustration at not achieving results faster.

Comment: *Frenetically* is (almost) a synonym of *frantically* (oerkelens)

Comment: @Kris Indeed, but it carries subtle nuances that may be more accurate in this context

Comment: My own sense of “frenetic” is that it covers a wider variety of motions than anything someone would do at a keyboard. There is also the fact that [“frenetic” is almost never used as an adverb](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frantically%2Cfrenetically%2C+frantic%2C+frenetic+&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1840&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3), so it may not be clear to the masses.

Answer (score 0):

Having just been given the idea by Invoker's contribution, I think *fumbling at the keyboard* gets the OP's desired points across very well.

Answer (score 0):

*Scrabbling* might be a good choice.

Although the OED defines it primarily as a writing action:

"To make marks at random; to write in rambling or scrawling characters; to scrawl, scribble."

It gives further definitions that describe animal behaviour as:

"To scratch about hurriedly with the claws or paws; hence, of a person, to scratch or scrape about with the hands or feet" which gives a sense of the frenetic action of quick nervous typing.

The OED further defines it as "To struggle or *scramble* for (something)" which can also work to describe the struggle to find the sought information.

Then *scramble* is defined as "To collect or gather up hastily or in disorder" which again would give the impression of hastily collecting information.

Also, *scrabbling* sounds seriously onomatopoeic when you imagine clacking away on a noisy keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that comes to mind is *feverishly*.

Agreed about *fumbling* -- that clearly implies clumsiness and failure.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following phrase:

> He was *fumbling* while typing.

*Fumbling* - to do or handle something clumsily. (This is the effect ; the case is almost always *nervousness*)

Consider another example -

> She was *fumbling* while speaking on the stage.

Why? Because she was nervous.

Comment: Nah. Not working at all - you likely meant fidgeting and it does not work in this case

Comment: While some people may fumble when they are nervous, many people fumble for other reasons, I'm afraid. Nervousness may contribute, but I know plenty of people who can fumble in a very relaxed way.